# How to union in a way that will group "date" into different columns instead of combining everything in the same column

Tags: pyspark, group-by, union, parquet, databricks

I'm very new to pyspark. Here is the little situation, I created a dataframe for each file (9 in total, each file represent the counts for each month), then I need to union them all in one big df. The thing is I need it to come out like this with each month is its own separate column.

```
name_id |  2020_01 | 2020_02 | 2020_03
   1         23       43534     3455
   2         12       34534    34534
   3         2352     32525       23
```

However, with my current code, it put all months under the same column. I've been searching on the internet for a long time, but could not find anything to solve this (maybe I need groupby, but not sure how to do that). Below is my code. Thanks!

```
df1=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df2=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df3=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df4=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df5=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df6=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df7=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df8=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")
df9=spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:")

#union all 9 files
union_all=df1.unionAll(df2).unionAll(df3).unionAll(df4).unionAll(df5).unionAll(df6).unionAll(df7).unionAll(df8).unionAll(df9)
```

Here is the current output

```
name_id | count | date
1          23     2020_01
2          12     2020_01
1         43534   2020_02
2         34534   2020_02
```

Comment: I suppose this is an accidental duplicate of [How to union in a way that will group “date” into different columns instead of combining everything in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561472/how-to-union-in-a-way-that-will-group-date-into-different-columns-instead-of-c)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to union in a way that will group "date" into different columns instead of combining everything in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561472/how-to-union-in-a-way-that-will-group-date-into-different-columns-instead-of-c)